# How to make raw HTTPS requests using syscall

Tags: go, networking

I am trying to make a raw HTTPS request using "syscall" module in Go. If I use "net", I can use tls.Client to turn the net.Conn into a tls.Conn and make a request to HTTPS website normally, but it doesn't seem like there is a similar function in syscall. How can I do it?

P/S: This is my code to make a HTTP request in syscall:
package main

```golang
import (
    "syscall"
    "time"
)
func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        go func() {
            sysCall, err := syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_INET, syscall.SOCK_STREAM, syscall.IPPROTO_TCP)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            address := syscall.SockaddrInet4{
                Port: 80,
                Addr: [4]byte{78, 31, 67, 223},
            }
            connErr := syscall.Connect(sysCall, &address)
            if connErr != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            func() {
                defer syscall.Close(sysCall)
                _, err = syscall.Write(sysCall, []byte("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 78.31.67.223\r\n\r\n"))
                if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
            }()
        }()
    }
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
}
```

Comment: The sycall process is exactly the same, you create a socket and write the desired protocol over that socket. The fact that you want tls vs http doesn’t change the syscalls used

Answer (score 0):

TLS is handled in user space and not in the OS kernel. This means there is no syscall for handling HTTPS or TLS. Instead the full TLS stacks needs to be implemented in user space and only the TCP level data (i.e. TLS handshake, encrypted payloads) can be send and received using syscalls.

Given that a [tls.Conn](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Conn) object [can be created from a net.Conn](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Client) it should be doable to implement your own net.Conn compatible type using syscalls and then use crypto/tls as the TLS stack for this.